# PHP store and compare time

Tags: php

I am trying to create a class that keeps track of time....

I would like to store current Time in a variable? and update that variable every 10 min.

i.e:

```
$storetime = 0;
$time = 600; //10min is 600 sec
$timestamp = $time();
```

Now the function time gives a number like 6001409669977 this number goes +1 every sec, So is it possible to store the variable and check when it has grown by 600 that would mean 10 min;

Comment: is this for a website or command line application?

Answer (score 0):

```
class timeclass {
    public $saved;
    public function __invoke() {
        return mktime(0);
    }
}

$time = new timeclass();
$time->saved = $time();
sleep(10);
echo $time->saved;
```

__invoke works when you call the class with parameters
you can also use __toString

also, for time, do not forget to set it before:

```
 date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Lisbon");
```

more info: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)!